# How to switch between Salesforce DX orgs/projects when using Visual Studio Code

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, salesforcedx-cli-auth

**BACKGROUND**

Imagine you're working on 2-3 Salesforce projects each with a different target Orgs (sandboxes for different companies).

You're actively working on project 1 (coding, running tests, deploy source to the org etc) and in parallel to this, you need to make a couple of tweaks to project 2 and project 3 during the same time period.

Therefore you have 3 instances of Visual Studio Code open.

I realise I could run this command to tell SFDX which org is the default

```
sfdx force:config:set defaultusername=ALIAS_NAME
```

or

```
sfdx force:config:set defaultusername=name@example.com
```

**QUESTION**

Is there a setting in the `project-scratch-def.json` that will tell Visual Studio Code which Org it should run the Salesforce DX against?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you run `sfdx force:config:set` the value is set at the project level [unless you use the -g flag](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_config.htm#cli_reference_force_config). So running `sfdx force:config:set defaultusername=alias` in a project folder will make that the default org for the project and the commands that you run in vscode will respect that.

Comment: Thanks. So let me get this straight, I can set the `defaultusername` on a per folder basis?

Comment: That's correct. When you set a config value (including `defaultusername`) without the `-g` flag, the value is stored in the `.sfdx\sfdx-config.json` file in your project directory and used only for that project.

Comment: @JohnTowers where is that information stored? I can't find any reference to my devhub org in any file. Let's say I want to switch my current project directory to point to another debhub/scratch org

Comment: The project config is stored in `[project root]/.sfdx/sfdx-config.json'. There should be a `defaultusername` property that has the username or alias for the current default org. If you used -g to set the default the value is stored in the `.sfdx/sfdx-config.json` in your home folder. If you want to change the *just* the current project for another org you should run the command in my answer. That will update the config file and has the added benefit of validating the username/alias you pass in. You can technically edit the file directly but that bypasses the validation and is prone to error.